# assign GMSMapView to UIView in Swift

Tags: swift, google-maps

I have created these two variables

```
var googleMap = GMSMapView()

@IBOutlet weak var mapView: UIView!
```

I'm assigning googleMap to mapView in viewDidLoad()

```
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.mapView = self.googleMap //Throwing error as 'Google Maps SDK for iOS must be initialized via [GMSServices provideAPIKey:...] prior to use'
}
```

I'm providing key in AppDelegate.swift

```
func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    GMSServices.provideAPIKey("AIzaSyB6aQxEmza-wUpOPU60aREWReRIAEAvrHs")
    return true
}
```

Can anyone point me in the direction to solve this?

Answer (score 7):

You do not assign the GMSMapView to your UIView in that way. Here's how you do it

Change the class of your UIView to GMSMapView
[image]

Comment: Thank you Luke ! but i want to do it manually by code can i do that ?

Comment: @ISHWARCHOUHAN no you cannot do that, its set at compile time not run time

Answer (score 0):

first you should change the class of UIView to the GMSMapView from story board , then you should make a IBOutlet from that view in view controller and set camera and else like this

```
@IBOutlet weak var mapView: GMSMapView!    
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    mapView.camera = camera
}
```